# concatenation of two arrays

Tags: javascript

I have an array:

```
$scope.array2 = ["3","4","5"];
$scope.array = [["1"],["2"],["3"]];
$scope.array[0].concat(array2);
```

Expected output:

```
$scope.array = [["1","3","4","5"],["2"],["3"]];
```

But the array is unchanged after `concat`. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Found the error : $scope.array[0] = $scope.array[0].concat(array2);

Comment: Also: $scope.array[0].concat($SCOPE.array2);

Comment: @Carsten good catch. I wouldn't emphasise with capital letters though; JS variable names are case sensitive

Comment: @Phil couldn't underline or make it bold :)

Comment: You know what this post needs? Even more of exactly the same answer

Comment: @Phil I don't understand why people come barging in and give the exact same answer as someone who posted 5 mins earlier

Comment: @Cerbrus Really? You're going to add the angular tag again after I edited it away? It's just petty and it's even wrong to have it here, this post is in no way specific to angular, the use of $scope is irrelevant to the question

Answer (score 4):

To get the desired result, you'd have to do something like this:

```
$scope.array2 = ["3","4","5"];
$scope.array = [["1"],["2"],["3"]];
$scope.array[0] = $scope.array[0].concat($scope.array2);
```

[`Array.prototype.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) actually *returns* the result, instead of modifying it's subject.
You'll have to save the result of the `contact` to `$scope.array[0]`.

---

Also, have a look at [@Phil's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/283366/phil) [answer, using `push`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30931045/1835379), that also returns the desired result, without having to assign the result separately.

Comment: Isn't this answer the same as NexusDuck's answer ?

Comment: Only since I convinced him to fix his answer, @Mustaghees. Before that, his answer didn't provide the expected result, while mine did.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.prototype.push` to merge the the second array into the first which does mutate the original array as desired. Try

```
Array.prototype.push.apply($scope.array[0], $scope.array2)
```

Originally referenced here ~ [Example: Merging two arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push#Example:_Merging_two_arrays)

```js
var array2 = ["3","4","5"],
    array = [["1"],["2"],["3"]];

document.getElementById('array').innerHTML = 'array = ' + JSON.stringify(array);
document.getElementById('array2').innerHTML = 'array2 = ' + JSON.stringify(array2);

Array.prototype.push.apply(array[0], array2);
document.getElementById('zomg').innerHTML = 'ZOMG! ' + JSON.stringify(array);
```

```html
<pre id="array"></pre>
<pre id="array2"></pre>
<pre id="zomg"></pre>
```

Comment: Nice use of apply here. +1

Comment: @Cerbrus it seems strange that `concat` can take either an array or variable arguments yet `push` is limited to the latter. `apply` to the rescue even though it's not as pretty

Comment: But then again, if `push` could take an array, how'd you push an "sub-array" to your target array? I figure that's why you can't concat arrays with push.

Comment: @Cerbrus that's a fair call

Answer (score 1):

The concat function returns a new array that is concatenated and leaves the original arrays unchanged.

Try :

```
    $scope.array2 = ["3","4","5"];
    $scope.array = [["1"],["2"],["3"]];
    $scope.array[0] = $scope.array[0].concat($scope.array2);
```

Comment: You're not changing `$scope.array`. Simply put: this answer doesn't do what the OP wants.

Comment: the OP didn't know it outputs a new array, I doubt he wants to change the original array as this is rarely the case

Comment: He _explicitly_ states his _"Expected output"_ is a modified array.

Comment: What the OP expects isn't necessarily what he wants because he didn't know it was possible, if you've never tasted chocolate you'll never feel the need for chocolate

Comment: I disagree, in this case. Any way, say the OP does want the array in a new variable, your answer _still doesn't work_, because `$scope.array3` equals `["1", "3", "4", "5"]`, now. That's not the OP's expected output.

Comment: @Cerbrus Fair enough. Anyway, the confusion of the OP was caused by the fact that `concat` doesn't change the original arrays, now that he knows that, the exact method of how to get what he wants is as irrelevant as it is trivial imo.

Comment: Sure, how doesn't matter that much, as long as the OP ends up getting the correct output, right? Your answer isn't in any way returning the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

As [Array.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) returns *a new* array, you must reassign the return value:

```
$scope.array[0] = $scope.array[0].concat(array2);
```

Comment: That's going to lose the `['2'], ['3']` entries which were initially part of `$scope.array`

Answer (score 1):

`concat` doesn't change the original array, you should do like below:

```
  $scope.array[0] = $scope.array[0].concat(array2);
```